# How much database ( size ) is suitable to store in the local storage of Meteor?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have been using Meteor for a while and totally in love with this framework. However, I have one curiosity.

Meteor keep one replica of database in the local storage of browser. But in some cases, for example, fetching details of the user in a website of around 100,000 users, it make more sense to not publish this collection and fetch this information directly from the server using their call/method functions.

So I would like to understand how and where Meteor store database in the local storage ? What is maximum database I should keep before making any performance impact on user's browser ?

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: Meteor stores it in memory on the client side, and by default none of this data is persisted (it is thrown away as soon as you close the browser tab). It is not really a database, more like client side cache.

Comment: @imslavko - Could you point me to any doc/article by Meteor on this ?

Comment: https://www.meteor.com/mini-databases